# Oracle EBS 12.2.4 Integration with ADF

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I want to use the Hierarchical Viewer of ADF and display as a component in oaf page using Rich Content the problem is when i run the application and with Rich Content Properties set as defined in the link it displays nothing not even an error.

Properties of My Rich Content item on my OAF Page
Item Style: RichContent
Content Type : Others
Destination Function : MyOwnDestinationFunction

I have followed the exact same steps as mentioned in the link: 
http://sushantsharmaa.blogspot.com/2013/09/19-embedding-adf-region-into-oaf-page.html

Currently working on EBS version 12.2.4 and Jdev 10.1.3.5 for OAF dev and Jdev 11g R2(for adf dev)

Comment: Any errors in the logs ?

Comment: @MrAdibou no it's not showing any errors, in the beginning it showed that "You are not authorized to view this page" mainly because i didn't register the function properly to a responsibility and after i assigned it and ran from that resp it is showing blank.